# Error al crear virtual host para Symfony

Tags: symfony2, virtualhost

¿Qué pasos debo seguir para configurar un virtual host en Symfony? Yo uso xampp. Siguiendo un tutorial he visto que debo añadir esto en httpd.conf (en mi caso parece que debo hacerlo en httpd-vhosts.conf):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80    

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mySymfonyProjectV2\Symfony\web"
DirectoryIndex app.php
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\mySymfonyProjectV2\Symfony\web">
AllowOverride All
Allow fromm All
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_mySymfonyProjectV2.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Pero esto me da un problema y es que al reiniciar Apache ya no arranca dando el error

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
17:07:16  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
17:07:16  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
17:07:16  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
17:07:16  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
17:07:16  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
17:07:16  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

¿qué pasos debo dar para crear correctamente un virtual host?

Answer (score 0):

Yo veo varias cosas:

No se si sea un error de escritura en la pregunta... pero tienes una linea

```
Allow fromm All
```

debería ser con una sola 'm':

```
Allow from all
```

O tambien, dependiendo de tu version de apache, la configuracion podria ser así:

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\mySymfonyProjectV2\Symfony\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```